# ffmpeg incompatible with output codec id

Tags: ffmpeg

Trying to create the dash segments with the below command:

```
./ffmpeg -y -err_detect careful -analyzeduration 8000000 -probesize 4000000 -rtbufsize 300000 -flush_packets 0  -fflags +genpts+discardcorrupt -f mpegts -i  Sample.ts -c copy -f dash -window_size 40 -min_seg_duration 8000000 -use_timeline 1 -use_template 1 live.mpd
```

But I get below error:

```
[mp4 @ 0x3fc0280] Tag [27][0][0][0] incompatible with output codec id '28' (avc1)
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid data found when processing input
```

ffmpeg release/3.4.
dashenc.c is on

```
commit 1b8ef01f04ab2210a26b59d3a1a62daed52ce88a
```

Instead of dash If I use mp4 there are no issues.

Do we need to compulsorily transcode?

Comment: Add `-vtag avc1` as an output option and check

Comment: It works !!! Thank you...